# Using Angular component by json data

Tags: angular

I have a lot of card component they are different type. I am getting data of card list from a json array.

```
[ 
   {id: 1, type: "flower"}, 
   {id: 2, type: "tree"}, 
   {id: 3, type: "animal"}
]
```

And I have created Angular components  of these types:

```
<flower></flower>
<tree></tree>
<animal></animal>
```

So I want to add these as dynamically in my app.componnet.html template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  data: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.data = [ 
       {id: 1, type: "flower" }, 
       {id: 2, type: "tree" }, 
       {id: 3, type: "animal" }
    ];
  }
}
```

my json data comes from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply try `*ngIf` like this.

**TS**

```
jsonData = [ 
   {id: 1, type: "flower"}, 
   {id: 2, type: "tree"}, 
   {id: 3, type: "animal"}
];
```

**HTML**

```html
<div *ngFor="let data of jsonData; let i = index">
   <flower *ngIf="data.type == flower"></flower>
   <tree *ngIf="data.type == tree"></tree>
    <animal *ngIf="data.type == animal"></animal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`NgSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) like:

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="type">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="flower">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="tree">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="animal">...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

Comment: Using ngFor loop?

Comment: You can wrap the `ngSwitch` elements with a `ngFor`. Like the answer of Askirkela

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch).

```html
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="d.type">
    <tree *ngSwitchCase="'tree'"></tree>
    <flower *ngSwitchCase="'flower'"></flower>
    <animal *ngSwitchCase="'animal'"></animal>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Multiple div tags will be added in this stuation. Can I change `div` with `ng-container `